# Find all references short key in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I cant believe there is no "Find All References" short key in Visual C++ from VS2010. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

The default hotkey is Shift+F12.

This is configurable.  In Tools => Options, browse to the Environment => Keyboard page and search for **Edit.FindAllReferences**.